# Custom Page type and variables

Tags: 7, theming

In my preprocess_page() function, I'm setting variables based on the user that is logged in.

I created a custom page that is used as a Welcome page with the information about the user that I set in the variables in the preprocess_page() function.

The problem I have is that the page is not allowing me to put the print statements to echo out the variable, i.e.

```
<h1 style="font-size:18px; padding-bottom:3px;"><?php print $FirstName. " ".$LastName; ?></h1>
```

It doesn't echo out the variable values.

Also, I need later to do something based on the value of a variable. I have tried using an if statement like this:

```
<?php                
  if($designations == 'ABCDE') {
?>                
              <td align="center" style="width: 40px;"><img src="images/abcde.png" alt=""></td>
</php                  
  } else {
?>
              <td align="center" style="width: 40px;">&nbsp;</td>
<?php                
   }
```

but all it does is print out part of the PHP:

```
if($designations == 'ABCDE') {
?>
} else {
?>
```

What am I doing wrong here???

Updated (Added preprocess_page function code):

```
function mix_and_match_preprocess_page(&$vars) {
  $vars['page_color'] = theme_get_setting('mix_and_match_page_bg');
  if(user_is_logged_in()) { 
    // Get the user's info and assign the values to variables.
    $vars['ParticipantID'] = 1007945;
    $vars['Username'] = 'JOESMITH';
    $vars['Password'] = 'passwd';
    $vars['FirstName'] = 'Joe';
    $vars['MiddleName'] = '';
    $vars['LastName'] = 'Smith';
    $vars['Suffix'] = '';
    $vars['PreferedEmailAddress'] = 'joe_smith@mysite.com';
  } // if($logged_in)  
}
```

Showing new code and results:
This code:

```
<h1 style="font-size:18px; padding-bottom:3px;"><?php print $FirstName. " ".$LastName; ?></h1>
```

produces (When view source):

```
<h1 style="font-size:18px; padding-bottom:3px;"><?php print $FirstName. " ".$LastName; ??></h1>
```

this code:

```
drupal_set_message('I got here');
<?php if($designations == 'ABCDE': ?>                
                  <td align="center" style="width: 40px;"><img src="images/cic-35x29.png" alt=""></td>
drupal_set_message('I got here');
<?php else: ?>
                  <td align="center" style="width: 40px;">&nbsp;</td>
<?php endif; ?>
```

produces (When view source):

```
drupal_set_message('I got here');<br />
<?php if($designations == 'UACIC'): ??>
<td align="center" style="width: 40px;"><img src="images/cic-35x29.png" alt="" /></td>
<p>drupal_set_message('I got here');<br /><?php else: ??></p>
<td align="center" style="width: 40px;"> </td>
<p><?php endif; ??>
```

Comment: it would help very much if you posted here your _preprocess_page function code where you're setting those variables.

Comment: There's a typo in your code - on the 5th line you have "</php" instead of "<?php"

That could munge things up pretty good...

Comment: @jmarkel, that didn't help.

Comment: @Alex, see updated post. I'm using Mix and Match theme.

Comment: I'd put some `drupal_set_message('I got here');` style debugging in there to make sure all your logic is actually happening.  Also, from a pure style and ease of reading standpoint, I'd use the `<?php if(foo): ?> ////// <?php endif; ?>` style in your templates instead of the `{}` style you have now, too.

Comment: Is the page code you've provided being used in a node (i.e. with PHP in your node content) or within a template (i.e. welcome--page.tpl.php)?

I could be barking up the wrong tree but I ask because it almost looks as if you're expecting php to be run but instead the node is being rendered as Filtered HTML.

Comment: Yes, I guess I'm going to change directions and do this a little differently. How would I go about making this page a template? I created it as a Custom Page in the admin interface.

Comment: Even as a custom page it ought to work (assuming you put the preprocess code in your theme's template.php), but in order to do so you have to 1)make sure the Core "PHP Filter" module is enabled and 2)make sure the node's Input Format is set to "PHP code." Not the most secure or maintainable way to do things, but is should work.

Comment: Security is not going to be an issue here because this is an informational site that we control the information being shown. Users are NOT going to be able to post any information or comments at all. Thanks. It you want to post this suggestion as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you put the preprocess code in your theme's template.php, coding this inside a node ought to work  - but in order for it to do so you have to

1. make sure the Core "PHP Filter" module is enabled and
2. make sure the node's Input Format is set to "PHP code."

As I noted, this is not the most secure or maintainable way to do things, but it'll let you do what you want without messing about in page or node templates.